# Invalid cd_ambient_conf.xml

Tags: experience-manager, configuration, ambient-data-framework, session-preview

Reviewing the documentation [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#docid=cd_ambient_confN10006&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=cd_ambient_confReference.ConfigNodeN10006.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoccd_ambient_confN10006&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DExcludedPaths&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1404417393909&currentQuery=ExcludedPaths&currentScope=), I think this should be a valid `cd_ambient_conf.xml`, however my log files say differently. They report error as per below:

> ERROR XMLConfigurationReader - Error while validating file
>   'cd_ambient_conf.xml' with schema 'schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd'.
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'ExcludedPaths'. One of '{Cookies, ClaimStoreProvider}' is
>   expected.

Here is my `cd_ambient_conf.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="6.1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd">
    <!-- <Security>
        <RequestValidator>com.tridion.webservices.security.validator.OAuth2RequestValidator</RequestValidator>
        <SharedSecret>sample_passphrase</SharedSecret>
    </Security> -->
    <!-- Cookies settings -->
    <!-- <Cookies> <Cookie Type="Tracking" Name="myTrackingCookie" Path="/"/> <Cookie Type="Session" Name="mySessionCookie" Path="/"/> </Cookies> -->
    <Cartridges>
        <!-- Example cartridge definition -->
        <!--
        <Cartridge File="cd_ambient_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
        -->
        <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
        <Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
    </Cartridges>
    <ExcludedPaths>
        <Path>/path1</Path>
        <Path>/path2</Path>
        <Path>/path3</Path>
    </ExcludedPaths>
    <ClaimStoreProvider>com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStoreProvider</ClaimStoreProvider>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your link to the docs, you are using Tridion 2011 SP1.  There was a hotfix that addressed this issue and it should be part of the Hotfix Rollup 2 release.